# Need help showing a monthly payment to customer and HTML estimate.

Tags: javascript, html, variables, output, liquid

I have a estimating system that allow me to insert html code. We have started offer some financing. I was able to insert the code for a loan calculator but we  know the length of our loans, the rates and the total amount estimated. I need to figure out how to set the input terms with the job total " {{ charge.total | currency }}" being the only variable. I would like the output a sentence (not table) that read like this:

> We can offer you a 132 month financing  plan at 9.99% APR that will
>   give you a monthly payment close to **$XXX.xx***_*____Small print

I was told that stack over flow was filled with smart coders who like little changes. I wouls also be happy if anyone know of a business that would help with this type of small coding question.

Here the code that I have tried to re-purpose:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function showpay() {
 if ((document.calc.loan.value == null || document.calc.loan.value.length == 0) ||
     (document.calc.months.value == null || document.calc.months.value.length == 0)
||
     (document.calc.rate.value == null || document.calc.rate.value.length == 0))
 { document.calc.pay.value = "Incomplete data";
 }
 else
 {
 var princ = document.calc.loan.value;
 var term  = document.calc.months.value;
 var intr   = document.calc.rate.value / 1200;
 document.calc.pay.value = princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + intr), term)));
 }

// payment = principle * monthly interest/(1 - (1/(1+MonthlyInterest)*Months))

}

// -->
</script>

The results of this loan payment calculator are for comparison purposes only.
They will be a close approximation of actual loan
repayments if available at the terms entered, from a financial institution. This
is being
provided for you to plan your next loan application. To use, enter values
for the
Loan Amount, Number of Months for Loan, and the Interest Rate (e.g.
7.25), and
click the Calculate button. Clicking the Reset button will clear entered
values.
<p>
<center>
<form name=calc method=POST>
<table width=30% border=5>
<tr><th bgcolor="#aaaaaa" width=25%><font color=black>Description</font></th>
<th bgcolor="#aaaaaa" width=25%><font color=black>Data Entry</font></th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eeeee">Loan Amount</td><td bgcolor="#eeeee" align=right><input
type=text name=loan
size=10></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eeeee">Loan Length in Months </td><td bgcolor="#eeeee"
align=right>(Terms 132mo 47mo 37mo)<input type=text
name=months size=3></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eeeee">Interest Rate </td><td bgcolor="#eeeee" align=right>( Rates 9.99%  7.99% 5.99%)<input
type=text name=rate
size=3></td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor="#eeeee">Monthly Payment</td><td bgcolor="#2E64FE"
align=right><em>Calculated</em> <input
type=text name=pay size=10></td></tr>
<tr><td  bgcolor="#eeeee"align=center><input type=button onClick='showpay()'
value=Calculate></td><td bgcolor="#eeeeee" align=center><input type=reset
value=Reset></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<font size=1>Enter only numeric values (no commas), using decimal points
where needed.<br>
Non-numeric values will cause errors.</font>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Month Financing Plan Examples**
For more information please go to our website.

http://www.generation3electric.com/financing" target="_blank">www.GEN3Electric.com

 ****A 12 month financing plan at 0% APR that will give you a monthly payment of    {{ job.total | divided_by:12| currency }}**

window.onload = function showpay() {

```
var princ = "{{ job.total }}";

var term1 = 132;
var intr1 = 9.99 / 1200;
var intrrate1 = 9.99;

var term2 = 47;
var intr2 = 7.99 / 1200;
var intrrate2 = 7.99;

var term3 = 37;
var intr3 =5.99 / 1200;
var intrrate3 = 5.99;

var cost1 = princ * intr1 / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr1), term1)));
var cost2 = princ * intr2 / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr2), term2)));
var cost3 = princ * intr3 / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr3), term3)));
var payment1 = Math.round(cost1);
var payment2 = Math.round(cost2);
var payment3 = Math.round(cost3);
var content = "**A  " 
              + term1 
              + " month financing plan at " 
              + intrrate1 + "% APR that will give you a monthly payment close to $"
              + payment1 
              +".**<BR> **A "
              + term2 + " month financing plan at " 
              + intrrate2 + "% APR that will give you a monthly payment close to $"
              + payment2 + ".**<BR>**A  " 
              + term3 + " month financing plan at " + intrrate3 
              + "% APR that will give you a monthly payment close to $"
              + payment3
              + ".**<BR>"   ;
document.getElementById("financing").innerHTML = content;
```

;}